# Embed another SVG into a path

Tags: svg

I'm having a hexagon shape path. I need to animate the background color of the hexagon, and the hexagon needs to contain another SVG icon.

Something like this (i know right this is not how it works):

```
<svg id="hexagon">
    <path fill="animatedColor">
        <svg id="icon"></svg>
    </path>
</svg>
```

As u can see, i can't define a pattern to use to fill, and that's the issue. I can't use exact widths as the whole itself is a responsive hexagon grid and it's generated on pageload.

Or is there any way to have both background image and color like in CSS?

Comment: make the icon a pattern and set the path fill to the pattern.

Comment: Robert is referring to a `<pattern>` element.  See: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns